Romantic comedy with young male secretary and elder blonde female boss
I hope someone remembers this movie that I want to see again, but I neither know the title nor any of the actors... I saw this some years ago, I guess it was an American TV movie, but I'm not entirely sure. It certainly was a movie with English language. Maybe it's from the 90s?
The story line was simple: a blonde female boss (about 40 years old) needs a new secretary very soon and she takes a male one who is in his late 20s. They fall in love and there is some game with hiding their love from the others, of course with an happy end. It's a romantic comedy. That's all I remember. Any clues?

Sounds like a common plot. Any other details would be helpful. (Similar plot to "The Proposal" from 2009, starring Sandra Bullock and Ryan Reynolds, but Sandra isn't blonde.)

That sounds nothing like The Proposal...

Sounds like the relationship between Rachel and Tag, which is the subject in several episodes of the show Friends. But I suppose that's not what you're looking for..

Brenda Morgan (Donna Mills, Knots Landing) is a beautiful, successful attorney who has everything a woman could want, so why won't anyone marry her? While everyone her is finding "Mr. Right," Brenda can't seem to figure out what she's doing wrong! Searching again for a new secretary, Brenda is overpowered by a handsome younger man who convinces her to hire him.
MOVIE -->The World's Oldest Living Bridesmaid 
with Donna MILLS
